# Why does this VB6 ActiveX Class Terminates Instantly?

Tags: class, dll, vb6, activex

Given the following ( extremely simple ) example :

```
VERSION 1.0 CLASS
BEGIN
  MultiUse = -1  'True
  Persistable = 0  'NotPersistable
  DataBindingBehavior = 0  'vbNone
  DataSourceBehavior  = 0  'vbNone
  MTSTransactionMode  = 0  'NotAnMTSObject
END
Attribute VB_Name = "Foo"
Attribute VB_GlobalNameSpace = False
Attribute VB_Creatable = False
Attribute VB_PredeclaredId = False
Attribute VB_Exposed = False
Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    MsgBox "Initialized!"
End Sub

Private Sub Class_Terminate()
    MsgBox "Terminated! ( FFFUUUUUUUUU )"
End Sub
```

When I declare this class within another class and attempt to instantiate it :

```
'Bar Class
Dim FooClassObject As Foo
Private Sub Class_Initialize( )
    FooClassObject = New Foo
End Sub
```

Foo is instantiated, but then immediately terminates.

Why?

Comment: `Set FooClassObject = New Foo` - If the problem persists then the `Bar` instance terminates because for example it drops out of scope.

Comment: @AlexK. Set, hmm? Okay thanks.

Comment: Yeah, VB6 requires the use of the `Set` keyword when instantiating an object.